# Typescript self executing function won't fire if there is an import

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this Typescript:

```
(()=> {
console.log('called boot'); // 'called boot'
})();
```

resulting JS:

```
(function () {
    console.log('called boot');
})();

define("StockMarketService", ["require", "exports", "jquery"], function(require, exports, $) {
    "use strict";
    var StockMarketService = (function (_super) {
        __extends(StockMarketService, _super);
        ...blah...
        return StockMarketService;
    }(Riot.Observable));
    exports.StockMarketService = StockMarketService;
});
```

VS Typescript:

```
import {StockMarketService} from "./services/stockmarket-service";
(()=> {
    console.log('called boot'); //NOTHING HAPPENS.
})();
```

Resulting JS:

```
define("StockMarketService", ["require", "exports", "jquery"], function(require, exports, $) {
    "use strict";
    var StockMarketService = (function (_super) {
        __extends(StockMarketService, _super);
        ...blah...
        return StockMarketService;
    }(Riot.Observable));
    exports.StockMarketService = StockMarketService;
});
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
  "use strict";
  (function () {
    console.log('called boot');
  })();
});
```

In the second version the IFFE no longer works. This is the entry point to the application. It's not a module. I just want to execute the IFFE. All the dependencies are in the one file, and I need to reference/use them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: import and export statement automatically makes a file into a module...You don't need to explicitly define a module for it...

Comment: Hmmm that's the problem. Anytime you import/export module that file becomes a module. So therefore, it will be wrapped in a `define([],func)` block... and therefore not immediately executable. What a pain that is.

Answer (score 0):

> In the second version the IFFE no longer works.

The second example is **module** ([more on this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html)). Module bodies only execute if *something requests the module*. If you use the module (somewhere in the chain) from your application root the module body would execute.

Comment: If used in another typescript file, that maybe the case. But this is a bootstrap. It's called up as such: `System.import('js/app.js').then(function(boot){boot();});` See the issue with that?

Answer (score -1):

any js code is valid TypeScript code,

so change

```
import {StockMarketService} from "./services/stockmarket-service";
```

(()=> {
    console.log('called boot'); //NOTHING HAPPENS.
})();

to

```
import {StockMarketService} from "./services/stockmarket-service";
```

(function () {
    console.log('called boot');
})();

Comment: won't work. It's still trapped in that define block — compiled code reads: `define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    (function () {
        console.log('called boot');
        debugger;
    });
});`